# Is plotting data from various sources possible?

Tags: bokeh

Is there a way to create a plot that is defined in terms of more than one source?

```py
source1 = ColumnDataSource({'x': [1,2,3]})
source2 = ColumnDataSource({'y': [5,5,7]})
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.circle(x='x', y='y', size=20, sources=[source1, source2])
```

Alternatively, is there a way to merge, combine or link sources on the client side? Possibly using some custom javascript?

My motivation is to be able to update the sources independently to minimize traffic. `source1` might be updated a lot while `source2` is mostly static.

Answer (score 0):

When considering a stand-alone BokehJS app you could take advantage of the `AjaxDataSource` (see [Bokeh documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html)) where you can set a `polling_interval` to define how often the data should be updated and you could add a JS callback (`adapter`) executed at each update where you can simply concatenate all your data sources into one data source. In [this example here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.1.0/examples/howto/ajax_source.py) Flask is used for serving the data. I guess in your application you would like to split this one app into 2 apps: one server app for serving the data and another stand-alone Bokeh JS app consuming the data

Answer (score 0):

Theres no officially endorsed way to drive a single glyph from multiple data sources. But, you could accomplish this by passing additional data sources as `args` to a [`CustomJSTransform`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#customjstransform), and pulling values from the extra data sources, instead returning a transformation of the standard `xs` values.

This is 1000% not what was intended as standard usage for `CustomJSTransform`, so I will leave demonstration as an exercise to the reader.